# como obtener y mostrar por consola datos obtenidos de inputs?

Tags: javascript, html5, formularios

me estoy volviendo loco tratando de obtener los datos de los inputs de un formulario.. Este lo quiero usar para luego crear un array de objetos e incrustarlos en la página mediante javascript. Esto no es relevante pero si también me dan una idea de eso se los agradezco..
aquí mi código html y luego los scripts

````
        <form action="" id="form">
            <input type="text" id="userName" placeholder="Nombre y apellido">
            <input type="email" id="userEmail" placeholder="ejemplo@correo.com">
            <select name="select-service" id="userSelect">
                <option value="one">Servicio 1</option>
                <option value="two">Servicio 2</option>
                <option value="three">Servicio 3</option>
                <option value="four">Servicio 4</option>
            </select>
            <select name="day" id="day">
                <option value="monday">Lunes</option>
                <option value="tuesday">Martes</option>
                <option value="wednesday">Miércoles</option>
                <option value="thursday">Jueves</option>
                <option value="friday">Viernes</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" id="btn-reserve" value="Enviar">
        </form>
    </div>

// Aclaro que este es el script que dejé.. pero lo cambié muchas veces y con ninguna pude ver los 
//datos en la consola.. Este ejercicio debo hacerlo con javascript puro.. Aún no hemos visto la  
//parte de jQuery en el curso.. 

    function showEvents () {
        const form = getElementById('form')
        const userName = getElementById('userName').value;
        const userEmail = getElementById('userEmail').value;
        const userSelect = getElementById('userSelect').value;
        console.log(userName.value);
        console.log(userEmail.value);
        console.log(userSelect.value);
    }
     const btnReserve = getElementById('btn-reserve');
    
    
     btnReserve.addEventListener('click', showEvents)```
````

Comment: Btn-reverse deberia ser de tipo submit en vez de butto y deberias usar el evento submit en vez del evento click en el addeventlistener para capturar los valores del formulario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que corregir varias cosas. A saber:

1. A menos que quieras llamar a los campos `input` mediante su `id=` de algun modo, para que el formulario sea efectivo debes agregar tambien el atributo `name=` a los `input`.

Por ejemplo así:

```
<input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="Nombre y apellido">
```

De esta forma cumple la sintaxis correcta de un formulario al pulsar el boton `submit`.

2. No estás usando un boton tipo `submit` en `Enviar`. Te recomiendo que lo hagas para que puedas recuperar los datos en el javascript que te mostraré a continuación.

Por lo tanto deberias dejarlo así:

```
<input type="submit" id="btn-reserve" value="Enviar">
```

3. Con estos cambios puedes ejecutar este javascript para acceder a los valores recogidos al pulsar el boton `submit`.

Javascript:

```
// creamos un objeto partiendo de su id
var formElement = document.getElementById("form");

// escuchamos el evento submit y si surge ejecutamos una función
formElement.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {

  // deshabilitamos el comportamiento por defecto de submit
    ev.preventDefault();

  // capturamos los datos del formulario
  var formData = new FormData(formElement);

  // Mostramos las [claves, valores] capturados en consola
  for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]);
  }
});
```

El código es autoexplicativo. A partir de aquí implementa lo que necesites.

Te dejo un [enlace donde he ido practicando esta solución](https://jsfiddle.net/3q1L9yp5/).

Comment: Excelente, gracias!